# dell streak mini 5 upgrade os to v3 or above

Tags: root-access, dell

Is it possible to upgrade a dell streak mini5?
  android operating system  to v3   or above please?
if so how?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The last official release for the device was Android 2.3, and 3.0 was closed source so there are no custom ROMs.  By the time 4.0 came out, no one was interested in this device anymore (and I'm not sure it could even physically run 4.0).